# adding three Addthis vertical share counters fot "facebook, twitter, Share"

Tags: wordpress, share, addthis

I like this style from Addthis
http://www.addthis.com/gallery/vertical-share-counter#.TcQav2vpPqQ

but I need to apply this same effect to Twitter and FB also.
Is there any code/wordpress plugin to accomplish this ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to the "Get AddThis" page:
https://www.addthis.com/get-addthis#.TcRXuV0rtEc

At the bottom you will see there are more customization options.
You can add buttons to your style of choice by adding extra links to the code:
https://www.addthis.com/help/custom-buttons#.TcRX862QaQ-